# Specific cPanel settings (MX records etc.) to use office 365 for email

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, office365, cname

I am a hosting provider. I have WHM access (also client cPanel access).

My client purchased his domain from godaddy. With office 365 email. After change the Nameserver to my hosting he cannot receive emails (but can send).

I have configuration info provided by godaddy, but I think those are not for cPanel.

In the cPanel I have access to the following pages:

```
- cPanel Page: Simple DNS Zone Editor 
- cPanel Page: Advanced DNS Zone Editor 
- cPanel Page: MX Entry 
- WHM Page: DNS Functions » Edit MX Entry
- WHM Page: DNS Functions » Edit Zone Templates
```

Is there anyone can get me instruction for cPanel, So I can host domain on a cPanel based hosting, but can use office 365 for email. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the domain in Office 365, create the required TXT, CRV, CNAME records in **cPanel Advanced DNS Zone Editor**.

You will find many useful information on [Office 365 help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-suite-help/set-up-and-manage-domains-HA102819938.aspx#_Toc386205318).